# Ruby Tkinter scrollbar doesn't appear in its frame and allows scrolling past canvas bounds. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I've been fighting with Tkinter in ruby to try and get a proper scrollable frame working.

I've had the most success with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmlgrrXAqb4

I have translated what he does in the video into ruby and it "works", but only kinda. When I run the application I get a window similar to his with all of the buttons, but the scrollbar handle doesn't appear in it's frame and I can scroll past the content of the frame in both directions.

I'm trying to build an application that has a heavy use of scrolling, but I can't get past this. I am posting as a last resort. I've tried most of the examples I can find online, but I keep getting unexpected behavior. It is worth noting that I am on MacOS in case someone tries the code on Windows or Linux and it works for some reason.

```rb
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tkimg'

win = TkRoot.new
win.geometry "500x500"
win.resizable false,false

wrapper1 = Tk::Tile::Frame.new win
wrapper2 = Tk::Tile::Frame.new win

mycanvas = TkCanvas.new wrapper1
mycanvas.pack :side => "left", :fill => "both", :expand => "yes" 

yscrollbar = TkScrollbar.new :parent => wrapper1, :command => Proc.new {|*args| mycanvas.yview *args}
yscrollbar.pack :side => "left", :fill => "y"

mycanvas.configure(:yscrollcommand => Proc.new {|*args| yscrollbar.set *args })
mycanvas.bind "<Configure>", Proc.new {mycanvas.scrollregion = mycanvas.bbox("all")}

myframe = Tk::Tile::Frame.new mycanvas
TkcWindow.new(mycanvas, 0, 0, :anchor => "nw", :window => myframe)

wrapper1.pack :fill => "both", :expand => "yes", :padx => 10, :pady => 10
wrapper2.pack :fill => "both", :expand => "yes", :padx => 10, :pady => 10

for i in 0..50
    button = TkButton.new(myframe)
    button.text = "Button " + i.to_s
    button.pack
end

Tk.mainloop
```

Comment: Does your code work ? I have : `itemconfig.rb:115:in 'hash_kv': wrong argument type nil (expected Array) (TypeError)` for the line `TkcWindow.new(mycanvas, 0, 0, :anchor => "nw", :window => myframe)`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.

```rb
#The line of code below where the Configure event is bound needs to be:
mycanvas.bind "Configure" #...
#instead of:
mycanvas.bind "<Configure>" #...
```

Comment: Congratulations ! I have been trying all sorts of modifications. For me, your code works if I change `TkcWindow.new(mycanvas, [0, 0, :anchor => "nw", :window => myframe])`.

Comment: I had found `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245643/how-to-make-a-scrollable-frame-with-canvas-in-ruby-tk` but it doesn't work. The documentation about Ruby Tk is poor.